# How to display the output of a command in anaconda prompt in to a text file? (in real time)

Tags: append, stdout, overwrite, anaconda3

I'm running some instructions from Anaconda prompt. **I need the result of the instruction to written (appended/over written) in real time to a text file**. Any solution to this? Please help.
I have tried with
`(the command) > output.txt` //output.txt is the file into which I want the result to be written